# How to delete a character from an NSString when NSRange is specified?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uitextfielddelegate

I need to delete a character from an `NSString` when an `NSRange` is specified. I have a text field and I enter some text with number formatting and I get the value as `$1,234,567.00`.

Now i place my cursor after digit 5 and want to delete the number 5. In the Text delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` I get the range as `(7,1)` when I press backspace. I tried the following

```
modifiedFieldText = [modifiedFieldText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(range.location - 1, range.length) withString:string];
```

But I am not able to delete the correct character. Any suggestion on this would be of great help. Please correct me where I went wrong.

Comment: Why do you need to remove it yourself? Just return `YES` from `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` and it will be edited in the text field. You can access the edited value from `textField.text`.

Comment: No i cant do that because i have many conditions in the delegate method that are used to format the text in different ways. Once i remove the character i need to format the text again in $ format. If i return YES it will reach the end of the method and i cant format the text.

Comment: Why are you not just doing `[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]`? If you want what the textfield would have been should the edit be accepted, that's how you do it. BTW, the range `{7,1}` is correct for the `5` character, so I don't get why you're trying to subtract 1 from the `location`...

Comment: The next character was getting deleted if i use actual range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you must have some line of code that is modifying `modifiedFieldText` before you get to this line. You should make sure that the `range` is applied to the original `textField` contents, achieved by making the `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange` use the `textfield` directly, such as:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *modifiedFieldText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    // now do whatever else you want
}
```

With that code, if the text field contained `$1,234,567.00` and the user deleted the `5`, the range would be `{7, 1}`, and the resulting `modifiedFieldText` would be `$1,234,67.00`, which you can presumably proceed and reformat to adjust the punctuation as you see fit.

If you are still having troubles, update your question with a more complete rendition of your `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`.